# Three.js freezes Chrome completely, huge texture in GLTF model

Tags: google-chrome, three.js, freeze, gltf

I want to load a ludicrous, binary glTF object with only a few polygons (~250), and a huge texture of size 10,000 x 5,500 pixels. The file is "only" 20MB in size.

When I load it using Three.js, Chrome hangs in its entirety for nearly 15 seconds. When looking in the profiler, pretty much nothing is going on during the freezing time.

If you want to load the file yourself, you can download it at https://phychi.com/uni/threejs/models/freezing-monster.glb, and the whole scene can be visited at https://phychi.com/uni/threejs/ (until I've found a solution or given up).

[image: Chrome Profiler]

The behavior stays the same, whether I call GLTFLoader.load(), GLTFLoader.loadAsync(), or create my own Promise, and call .then(addToScene), without any awaits.

Does somebody have a magical solution? Or if not, how could I profile it more efficiently, seeing the internal calls? Or should I just open a bug report for Chrome/Three.js?

PS: Windows 10 Personal, Ryzen 5 2600, 32 GB RAM, RX 580 8GB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue should be resolved by upgrading the library to `r135`(the current release).

The releases `r133` and `r134` have a change that introduced a performance regression on Windows when using sRGB encoded textures.

Comment: Would also note that all textures (excluding special compressed GPU texture formats) must be decompressed before uploading to the GPU. A 10,000 x 5,500px texture will be about 300 MB after it's decompressed, so that's still going to take a noticeable amount of time to decompress and upload – even with the bug fix in r135.